# How do I use :replay in SBT to replay previous commands against freshly compiled classes?

Tags: scala, sbt

In the sbt console, :replay resets execution and replays all previous commands.  I would have thought sbt would recompile your classes if there were changes and replay previous commands against your freshly compiled classes.  But that doesn't seem to be the case.  Do I need to use JRebel for this kind of workflow?  My goal is to be able to find a bug in the REPL, fix the bug, and then compile & re-run all previous commands with a single command like :reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:replay` is a command of the Scala REPL, not the SBT.

Try running `sbt console` with JRebel in one shell, and then, in a second shell run`sbt ~compile`.

The first will give you automatic reloading of recompiled classes; the second will recompile edited classes automatically.

Comment: Thanks, that's a simple but effective solution.

Comment: For more info on this approach see [this response](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12707490/148680) to _Scala sbt console - code changes not reflected in sbt console_