# SBT console - How to run stuff on initialization?

Tags: scala, sbt, lift

I am using sbt console to debug some web application, written with Lift Framework.

Every time running it, I run some commands to initialize framework.

```
import bootstrap.liftweb.Boot
(new Boot).boot
import ...some frequently used models from my app...
```

I want sbt to do this boilerplate every time I start it.

How to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simple way to do that, is put "initialCommands" rule in build.sbt.

This example:

```
initialCommands in console := """println("Hello from console")"""
```

will print in console, after initialization

```
Hello from console
```

Provided by https://stackoverflow.com/a/12703977/225767